# Apple Mail OAuth client_id for GSuite IMAP restriction

Tags: mail.app

We need to restrict IMAP access to GSuite so that only OAuth supporting apps can use it. This requires knowing the client id.

Does anyone know the **client_id** for the MacOS Mail app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on a Google page at https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en#zippy=%2Coauth-ids-for-common-email-clients

MacOS Apple Mail: 946018238758-bi6ni53dfoddlgn97pk3b8i7nphige40.apps.googleusercontent.com

iOS Apple Mail: 450232826690-0rm6bs9d2fps9tifvk2oodh3tasd7vl7.apps.googleusercontent.com